# Recovering Kafka consumer after acknowledgment.acknowledge(); was not called

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have implemented a simple Kafka consumer which implements AcknowledgingMessageListener. There is acknowledgment.acknowledge(); at the and of onMessage method and it is called every time when everything goes well or there was just a recoverable Exception. Everything works in this case.

But things may go wrong way and there may be an Error thrown (which I do not catch), JVM may crash etc. in the onMessage method before acknowledgment.acknowledge(); was called.

So application crashes but after restart it does not received any messages from the affected Kafka topic. Even Kafka restart does not help, application server restart does not help etc., but other topics work well, Kafka is not down.

What is the right Kafka consumer (or other) configuration get the application working again after such crash in onMessage? I want to receaved the not acknowledged message again and then all the other messages that have not been read yet. Manual acknowledgment is important, I do not want use the automatic acknowledgment mode.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

server.properties

max.poll.interval.ms=30000

session.timeout.ms=40000